# Returning ID from inserted record using a parameterized query in VB.NET and Oracle

Tags: vb.net, oracle

I am attempting to retrieve the id of the inserted record with no luck.  I've been able to successfully run the query, and the record is inserted, but I cannot get the inserted record id back.

Here is my function:

```
Public Function InsertFile(ByVal file_name As String, _
                           ByVal project_id As Integer, _
                           ByVal folder_id As Integer, _
                           ByVal public_access As Integer, _
                           ByVal isProtected As Integer, _
                           ByVal uploaded_by As Integer, _
                           ByVal file_description As String) As Integer
        Dim connection As New OracleClient.OracleConnection(sConnectionstring)
        Dim command As New OracleClient.OracleCommand()
        Dim file_id As Integer

        Try
            connection.Open()
            command = connection.CreateCommand
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            command.CommandText = "insert into data_file (file_name, project_id, folder_id, public_access, protected, uploaded_by, file_description) "
            command.CommandText += " values (:p1, :p2, :p3, :p4, :p5, :p6, :p7) returning file_id into :p8"
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("p1", file_name)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("p2", project_id)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("p3", folder_id)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("p4", public_access)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("p5", isProtected)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("p6", uploaded_by)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("p7", file_description)
            command.Parameters.Add("p8")
            command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            file_id = command.Parameters.Item("p8").Value.ToString()
        Catch ex As Exception
            ProjectData.SetProjectError(ex)
            Dim builder As StringBuilder = _strOracleErrorMessage
            builder.Remove(0, builder.Length)
            builder.Append("LAST ORACLE ERROR GENREATED: ")
            builder.Append(Now.ToString)
            builder.Append(ChrW(13) & ChrW(10))
            builder.Append("MESSAGE: ")
            builder.Append(ex.Message)
            ProjectData.ClearProjectError()
            Return file_id = -9999
        Finally
            connection.Close()
        End Try

        connection.Dispose()
        command.Dispose()
        GC.Collect()

        Return file_id

End Function
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

After digging around, I realized that I wasn't setting the `p8` parameter to output

I added the the following line:

```
command.Parameters.item(command.Parameters.Count -1).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
```

after

```
command.Parameter.Add("p8")
```

and I worked.